# 20.04.1 LTS Lost Drivers (Live Update Perhaps?)

Tags: drivers, usb, sound-blaster

After a few struggles, I had a successful 20.04 LTS installation that was fully operational.  Live Update seemed like a good idea, so I did enable it.  I typically leave my workstation powered on 24/7. I attempted to watch youtube videos on it a couple hours ago, but I was getting no sound from my Sound BlasterX G6.  It was working perfectly yesterday.

I performed a restart to check dmesg output when I found that I also lost my NVIDIA drivers. Ubuntu was starting at 640x640 resolution instead 2560x1440. I reinstalled the NVIDIA drivers and regained my previous resolution.  I cannot find how to reinstall the Sound BlasterX G6 drivers that the installation automatically installed.

Would anyone please share guidance on how to restore my sound?  Also, what caused all my drivers to be removed in the first place?

EDIT:

After Google searches, I am finding others have issues with this hardware.

I checked my dmesg from last boot to see the following:

```
[    8.839387] usb 2-1.8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=11
[    8.839388] usb 2-1.8: Product: Sound BlasterX G6
[    8.839389] usb 2-1.8: Manufacturer: Creative Technology Ltd
[    8.839390] usb 2-1.8: SerialNumber: 2F00614F63X
[    8.840454] input: Creative Technology Ltd Sound BlasterX G6 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.8/2-1.8:1.3/0003:041E:3256.0003/input/input3
[    8.897596] hid-generic 0003:041E:3256.0003: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [Creative Technology Ltd Sound BlasterX G6] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.8/input3
[    8.898421] hid-generic 0003:041E:3256.0004: hiddev1,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Device [Creative Technology Ltd Sound BlasterX G6] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.8/input4
[   13.012038] usb 2-1.8: USB disconnect, device number 11
[   13.509684] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[   13.745393] usb 2-1.8: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[   13.855577] usb 2-1.8: New USB device found, idVendor=041e, idProduct=3256, bcdDevice=11.60
[   13.855593] usb 2-1.8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=11
[   13.855594] usb 2-1.8: Product: Sound BlasterX G6
[   13.855595] usb 2-1.8: Manufacturer: Creative Technology Ltd
[   13.855596] usb 2-1.8: SerialNumber: 2F00614F631
[   13.856658] input: Creative Technology Ltd Sound BlasterX G6 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.8/2-1.8:1.3/0003:041E:3256.0005/input/input4
[   13.913634] hid-generic 0003:041E:3256.0005: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [Creative Technology Ltd Sound BlasterX G6] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.8/input3
[   13.914820] hid-generic 0003:041E:3256.0006: hiddev1,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Device [Creative Technology Ltd Sound BlasterX G6] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.8/input4
[   18.885457] xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   19.093604] usb 4-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[   19.301378] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[   19.309486] usb usb4-port2: attempt power cycle
```

Based on the dmesg output above, I shutdown the workstation.  When I powered it back on, my audio output is working again.

The only question I have is why my NVIDIA drivers were removed?

EDIT:

after running Software Updater, I am now seeing why the drivers I just installed this morning are being removed:

[image]

I just found nvidia-450 is drivers for my hardware.  Why would these be removed?  I will run the updater, restart, and see if I lose 2560x1440 resolution again. If so, this is why I am losing it.